# Access-Control-Allow-Origin with WebAPI

Tags: javascript, cors

I read a lot of threads about this issue and couldn't find a solution.

I created simple Web-API service project with 2 methods: `GET` and `PUT`.

Using this [guid](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-methods) I defined my service to enable cors without any restrictions:

1. put the following attribute above the controller class:

   `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]`
2. Inside `WebApiConfig`class I put the following configuration:

   ```
       var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
       config.EnableCors(cors);
   ```

   The Get method is working great, I'm invoke it from JS using this code:

[image]

The calling to the `PUT` method is defined by the next code:

```
   var addUser = function(domain, firstname, lastname, idsid){
            var config = {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers:  {
                'Content-Length': '4096'
            }};
            return $http.put('http://server:port/api/controller/Put?domain=dom&lastName=lastN&firstName=firstN', config);
        };
```

Here is the problem:
My `PUT` method which defined under same controller with same cors settings is throwing me the following exception:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server:port/api/controller/Put?domain=dom&lastName=lastN&firstName=firstN'. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9444' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400`

Why does it happens? I set the entire controller for accept cors requests but the `Put` method is refusing to work.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the Net tab. Look at the request being sent by Ajax. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes, Already done it and the address is fine

Answer (score 2):

Are you using angular for javascript client requests?
Because in angular, the second parameter for "$http.put" is the object of the request: put(url, data, [config]); 
So try transform your querystrig value in object, something like this:

```
var requestObject = {
                     domain: domain, 
                     lastName: lastName, 
                     firstName  : firstName
                    };
```

And send it, like this:

```
return $http.put('http://server:port/api/controller/Put', requestObject, config);
```

I'm sorry if I understood wrong, hope this helps! 
Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code in Your `<Script></Script>` tags

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    // Starts your Coding from here 
    var request = createCORSRequest("get", "<YOUR_URL>");
    if (request){
        request.onload = function(){
            //do something with request.responseText
        };
        request.send();
    }
```